# youtube api for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube

Is there a wrapper on youtube api for ruby on rails ? I understood that there is no official google api for ruby . i found on rubyForge some sort of wrapper but it is dated last 2007 : http://rubyforge.org/projects/youtube . Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching Github for Ruby/Rails projects is usually going to result in more relevant results:

There are several available that I found with [this search](https://github.com/search?type=Repositories&language=ruby&q=youtube&repo=&langOverride=&x=23&y=10&start_value=1).